# Multiplication of 4d and 2d matrices using pytorch

Tags: matrix, pytorch, multiplication

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication through a torch. What I want to do is multiply a 4d matrix by a 2d matrix.
For example, 4d has a size of (A,B,C,D), and 2d has a size of (D,C).

What I want is that the matrix of 2d is repeatedly matrix multiplied as much as the sizes of A and B of 4d, and the final size is in the form of (A,B,C,C).

I'd be grateful if you could point out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to compute is:

```
>>> for a, b in AxB:
...     R[a, b] = X[a, b]@Y
```

You can start with a loop over `A` and `B` and compute each matrix multiplication `(C,D)@(D,C)` which yield `(C,C)`. Overall you get a tensor of shape `(A, B, C, C)`, *ie.* A*C matrices of size `CxC`.

You can perform such operation using [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) (read more about [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html)):

```
>>> R = torch.einsum('abcd,de->abce', X, Y)
```

Notice how we used subscripts `e` different to `c`.
 The corresponds to the pseudo-code:

```
>>> R = torch.zeros(A,B,C,C)
>>> for a,b,c,d,e in AxBxCxDxC:
...     R[a,b,c,d] += X[a,b,c,d]*Y[d,e]
```

However, in this simple use case you can get away with multiplying `X` and `Y` straightaway because PyTorch handles broadcasting. So it comes down to:

```
>>> R = X@Y
```

Simple!

Comment: Consider marking this answer as valid (green checkmark on the right).

Answer (score -1):

The best would be if you invest some time to learn `einsum`:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html

More practical guide:
https://betterprogramming.pub/einsum-visualized-c050903145ef